# MySQL UNIQUE Constraint multiple columns condition

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, unique-constraint, unique-index

Well, i have a table with 4 columns(`id`, `event_id`, `group_id`, `isbn`), where id is PK, `event_id` and `group_id` are FK's, and my problem is:

I need the isbn number to be unique for each `event_id`, let me give you some examples of some rows that should be possible and some that should not:

```
 id | event_id | group_id | isbn
 (1,1,1,123) ok 
 (2,1,2,123) ok
 (3,1,4,123) ok
 (4,1,7,1234) ok
 (5,2,8,123) NOT OK, the 'isbn' must be unique for event_id('123' was already used in the first row with event_id = 1)
```

the `group_id` only appears once for each `event_id`, but if i make a unique contraint with the 3 columns i would be able to repeat the isbn just chaning the `event_id`, and i don't want that,once an `isbn` is used in an `event_id` it cant appear in another `event_id`, an `event_id`(let's say '1') can repeat the same `ibsn` as longe as it needs for each `group_id`

I know i kind of repeated the problem several times, but is a tricky question and i want to lower the chances of getting wrong answers

**EDIT1: about @Andomar answer, the isbn must be related to the group_id by the cardinality (1,n) 1-isbn -> n-group_id and the structure in the answer don't do that**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is that `event_id` is dependant on the  `isbn` . You need to normalize the table by splitting it into two:

**(Corrected):**

<strike>Remove</strike> Keep `isbn` in this - and add a `FOREIGN KEY (event_id, isbn)` constraint to the second table, below:

```
id | event_id | group_id | isbn
 1      1          1        123 
 2      1          2        123
 3      1          4        123 
 4      1          7        1234
 5      2          8        123     --- not allowed by the FK constraint
```

And create a new table with `isbn` as the primary key and a `UNIQUE (event_id, isbn)` key (and two foreign keys: `event_id` to `Event` table and `isbn` to (`Book`?), if you have a table where `isbn` is the primary or unique key):

```
event_id | isbn
   1        123 
   1       1234
```

Comment: Acctually worked, sorry, i had my second table with event_id marked as signed and in my first table it was unsigned so the columns were different, that is why i could not set it as foreign key, now i managed to do it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

To keep the `(event_id, isbn)` combination unique:

```
create unique index UX_YourTable_EventIsbn on YourTable(event_id, isbn)
```

Per the comment, if you'd like to have only one event per isbn, you could redesign the table relation.  Create a table called `isbn` that has a a primary key `isbn` and a field called `event_id`.  That way, an ISBN can have zero or one events associated with it.

```
isbn          isbn primary key, event_id
other_table   id, event_id, group_id
```

A query would look up the isbns for an event in the `isbn` table.

Comment: how this index prevents adding once 1, 123 and then 2, 123 for event_id, isbn? It would simply prevent adding 1,123 twice which far different from the question.

Comment: @NedretRecep: Good point, didn't read that in the question.  I'll update the answer.