# MySQL InnoDB table adding foreign key errno:150

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship, indexing

Well, i have two tables

#### publica_evento_grupo

```
Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra
id_evento_grupo int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment
id_evento       int(8)  unsigned    NO  MUL     
id_grupo        int(8)  unsigned    NO  MUL     
identificacao   varchar(55)         NO
```

#### publica_identificacao_publicacao

```
Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra
id_evento       int(8) unsigned NO  PRI     
identificacao   varchar(55)     NO  PRI
```

`publica_evento_grupo`.`id_evento` in  is a foreign key to a third table called **publica_evento** but is also a foreign key together with the column  to the table `publica_identificacao_publicacao`.`identificacao`. The problem is, I got to create the foreign key that relates **publica_evento_grupo** to **publica_identificacao_publicacao** by the key `id_evento`, but when I try to create the another FK with the column `identificacao`, it gives the errno below

```
 [Err] 1005 - Can't create table '#sql-1049_1980992' (errno: 150).
```

As you can see the table **publica_identificacao_publicacao** has two PK and that iss the reason that it has to be 2 FK to relate them, i didn't create the indexes yet, because as far as i know, i just have to create the indexes after adding the FK contraints, and I was able to create the FK contraint to the column `id_evento` between **evento_grupo** and **identificacao_publicacao**, i don't know why just the column `identificacao` is giving this error

**EDIT 1: @RolandBouman i don't have the permission to use that command SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS**

**EDIT 2: @Geoff_Montee acctually the command you passed worked, to undestand why i use that structure take a look at this question [MySQL UNIQUE Constraint multiple columns condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074400/mysql-unique-constraint-multiple-columns-condition)**

Comment: Do a `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` right after you encounter this error, and look for the heading `LAST FOREIGN KEy ERROR` in the output. Probably this is just a datatype mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error usually happens because there is a type mismatch between the referring table and the referred table. In this case, the types seem to match.

Have you considered having a constraint for both fields in the primary composite key? You might have to remove the existing foreign key constraint on `id_evento` first.

```
ALTER TABLE publica_evento_grupo ADD FOREIGN KEY 
    (id_evento, identificacao) REFERENCES 
    publica_identificacao_publicacao (id_evento, identificacao);
```

It seems as though the error in this case might be because you try to add a foreign key constraint to only **part** of a **composite** primary key.

Does `identificacao` exist in any other tables? Why do you want to add a foreign key constraint to only part of a composite primary key?

Think about it this way...

Let's say you do have a foreign key constraint in the `publica_evento_grupo` table to the `identificacao` field by itself. Let's also say in the `publica_identificacao_publicacao` table you have `(1, "some string")` and `(2, "some string")`. So if you delete `(2, "some string")`, but leave `(1, "some string")` in its place. The rows that refer to `(1, "some string")` in the `publica_evento_grupo` table will complain, even though they shouldn't!

So it sounds to me like you should add a foreign key constraint to all of a primary key or none of it.

Comment: what u said actually makes sense, thanks, i'll mark your answer as correct! :D

Answer (score 9):

Without the actuall DDL it's not so easy to say. I recommend doing:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

Immediately after you run into this error. In the output, look for a section that looks like:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
121026 22:40:18 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/#sql-154c_94:
foreign key(rid) references bla(id):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

You'll find detailed info there about what's wrong with your foreign key definition.

Comment: Good command for everyone to know. I'm willing to bet that it's because he wants a foreign key constraint on only part of a primary key though. Logically, it doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Heh, thanks. Actually I didn't read the question that carefully. Strangely enough Innodb actually allows you to create a foreign key on  the prefix of any index on the parent table. Even if that is not a unique index or primary key, and even if the prefix is not unique. Quirky, and without any realistic use case, but it is in fact allowed. (god knows why)